# Is Vue's $emit async operation?

Tags: vue.js

Just quick question, if I call this.$emit, should it be async function or I can expect this.$on's callback get called immediately?

Thanks,

Comment: According to their current source code, [no](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/a47a0ee287116df7f2b89b956fdb3a3ea6c6330c/dist/vue.runtime.js#L2658).

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Thanks so much. Just want to confirm: no mean it is sync?

Comment: The event handlers are executed immediately in a loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called immediately:
https://codepen.io/BeniaminH/pen/mdVNpaZ?editors=1111

```
methods: {
  emitEvent() {
    this.$emit('myEvent')
    console.log('emitted')
  },
},
mounted() {
  this.$on('myEvent', () => {
    console.log('triggered')
  })
}
```

Logs:

```
"triggered"
"emitted"
```

Comment: Thanks for this example

Answer (score 3):

I landed this question because I had a problem of having "old" values of props after emit. Here's the example

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['count'],
  methods: {
    emitEvent() {
      this.$emit('increment')
      console.log('after emit', this.count);
      Vue.nextTick(() => {
        console.log('next tick', this.count);
      })
    },
  },
  template: `<div>count {{count}}. <button @click="emitEvent()">emit</button></div>`
})

const example2 = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    count: 100,
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++;
    }
  },
  template: `<div id="example-2"><child :count="count" @increment="increment" /></div>`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

I expected that after emitting my `count` value will be updated immediately, but it's not.
It's updated in the next tick only. Keep this in mind when you expect that `$emit` is executed synchronously.